# Polynomial maximization: If $x^4+ax^3+3x^2+bx+1 \ge 0$, find the maximum value of $a^2+b^2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality, polynomials

If $x^4+ax^3+3x^2+bx+1 \ge 0$ for
all real $x$ where $a,b \in R$. Find the maximum value of $(a^2+b^2)$.                                                                        I tried setting up inequalities in $a$ and $b$ but in the end had a hideous two variable expression whose maxima I had to calculate using Partial Derivatives. There must be a better way of doing it. Thanks!

Comment: There exist a way to make it a quadratic optimization problem using the fact that $P$ is positive if an only if it can be written as $(ax^2+bx+c)^2+(dx^2+ex+f)^2$ and the problem becomes:Maximize $(ab+de)^2+(bc+ef)^2$ s.t. $a^2+d^2=1$ and $c^2+f^2=1$ and $2(ac+df)+b^2+e^2=3$ and this can be solved by computers, Note that your $a$ is $2(ab+de)$ for me and your $b$ is $2(bc+ef)$.

Comment: The function has no real roots at $a=b=0$; as you vary $a$ and $b$, when real roots first appear, you'll get a double root, i.e. $f$ and $f'$ have a common root for that pair $(a,b)$.  The resultant of $f$ and $f'$ gives the locus of $(a,b)$ for which $f$ has a double root.  Now use Lagrange multipliers to find the point $(a,b)$ with minimal $a^2+b^2$.  You get $a=b=5/2$.  But it's hard to claim this is "better," since you still have to calculate the gradient to do Lagrange multipliers.  But it *is* quite systematic.

Comment: @Tad But the answer is 40. There is also a hint provided in my worksheet regarding this question which says to that there exists a beautiful geometrical solution.

Comment: The answer is 40, clearly and it can be achieved for $a=\sqrt{20}; b=-\sqrt{20}$ or other way around. In my answer I've proven a more general statement, although it's kind of messy. If you have any problem understanding it I can explain it to you.

Comment: Aha - it looks like I interpreted the problem differently - a problem with English and implicit quantifiers.  The problem I solved was to find the maximum value of $a^2+b^2$ which *guarantees* that $f(x)\ge0, \forall x$.  (That value is $25/2$, in contrast to the maximum value of $a^2+b^2$ such that there's *some* pair $(a,b)$ with $f(x)\ge0,\forall x$, which I agree is $40$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've spent probably 4-5 hours studying this problem and this is what I found:

$$x^4 \pm 2\sqrt{c+2}x^3 + cx^2 \mp 2\sqrt{c+2}x + 1 \ge 0; \forall x,c \in \mathbb{R}$$

Which is true due to the fact that:

$$x^4 - 2\sqrt{c+2}x^3 + cx^2 + 2\sqrt{c+2}x + 1= (-x^2 + \sqrt{c+2}x + 1)^2 \ge 0$$

$$x^4 + 2\sqrt{c+2}x^3 + cx^2 - 2\sqrt{c+2}x + 1= (x^2 + \sqrt{c+2}x - 1)^2 \ge 0$$

So in our case $c=3$ so we have:

$$x^4 \pm 2\sqrt{5}x^3 + 3x^2 \mp2\sqrt{5}x + 1 \ge 0; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

And it's fairly easy to check that the coefficient infront of $x^3$ and $x$ can't have a bigger absolute value. Assume otherwise and we have:

$$x^4 + (2\sqrt{5} + m)x^3 + 3x^2 - (2\sqrt{5}+n)x + 1= (x^2 + \sqrt{5}x - 1)^2 +mx^3-nx$$

Now plug $x_1=\frac{3 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$ and we must have:

$$mx_1^3 - nx_1 \ge 0$$
$$mx_1^3 \ge nx_1$$
$$mx_1^2 \ge n$$
$$m\cdot \frac{7-3\sqrt{5}}{2} \ge n$$

Now plug $x_2=\frac{-3 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$ and we must have:

$$mx_2^3 - nx_2 \ge 0$$
$$mx_2^3 \ge nx_2$$
$$mx_2^2 \le n$$
$$m\cdot \frac{7+3\sqrt{5}}{2} \le n$$

Which clearly contradicts the previous statement. We get simular results if we try to make one of the coefficient bigger, while we are making the other smaller.

From all these contradictions we get $\mid a,b \mid \le 2\sqrt{5}$, so therefore:

$$a^2 + b^2 \le (2\sqrt{5})^2 + (2\sqrt{5})^2 = 20 + 20 = 40$$

It can be simularly proven that if: $x^4 + ax^3 + cx^2 + bx + 1 \ge 0; \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ for fixed c, then $max\{a^2+b^2\} = 8(c+2)$

Comment: Thanks a lot, ultimate thinking! I'll still be looking for the geometrical solution and after seeing your thought process, I guess we can somehow incorporate distance formula and triangle inequality. Once again, nice solution :)

Comment: @DarudeSandstorm Well I don't you can get a purely geometrical solution, although I think that a solution that uses linear algebra can be found. As for a purely geometrical solution I think of finding a distances on the plot of the function, but as far as I know the plot can't reveal much about the coefficients of the polynomial

Answer (score 0):

I'm still wondering about the "beautiful geometric solution," but there is another intuition that I think is useful.
The idea is that if $f(x) = x^4 + ax^3 + 3x^2 + bx + 1 \geq 0,$ 
then $f(x)$ can have only multiple roots (else its graph would cross the $x$ axis). A root of multiplicity $3$ is impossible (since it would imply another single root), and it is easy to show that a root of multiplicity $4$ also is impossible (since the terms $x^4$ and $1$ imply the root would have to occur at $x=\pm1,$ and this is inconsistent with the therm $3x^2$). Hence we have two or fewer roots of multiplicity $2.$

Briefly considering how $f(x)$ changes as we vary $a$ and $b,$
if $f(x) \geq 0$ for some pair of values of $a$ and $b$ of the same sign,
then we can reverse the sign of one of those coefficients while preserving
the property that $f(x) \geq 0.$  Hence whatever the maximum value of
$a^2 + b^2$ is, $a$ and $b$ have opposite signs.
The maximum value occurs when there is a double root on each side of the $y$ axis, since roots on only one side would enable one of the coefficients (either the positive one or the negative one) to have a larger magnitude.

In short, $f(x) = k(x - p)^2(x - q)^2$ for some positive number $k$ and some real numbers $p$ and $q.$
Multiplying this out, we have two ways to write $f(x)$ as a polynomial
in standard form,
\begin{align}
f(x) &= kx^4 - 2k(p + q)x^3 + (p^2 + 4pq + q^2)x^2 - 2kpq(p + q)x + kp^2q^2\\
&= x^4 + ax^3 + 3x^2 + bx + 1.
\end{align}

Comparing leading terms, we find that $k=1,$ and therefore the constant terms show that $p^2q^2 = 1,$ that is, $\lvert pq \rvert = 1$.
From the terms in $x$ and $x^3$ we see that $b = pqa$;
since $a$ and $b$ have opposite signs, $pq = -1$ and $q = -\frac1p.$
We can therefore equate the terms in $x^2$ as follows:
$$
p^2 - 4 + \left(\frac1p\right)^2 = 3.
$$
Setting $u=p^2,$ rearranging terms and multiplying by $u,$
we have $u^2 - 7u + 1 = 0,$ which has roots 
$u = \frac12(7 \pm 3\sqrt5).$ We may recognize $\frac12(7 + 3\sqrt5)$ as the fourth power of the golden ratio.
Since $p = \pm\sqrt u,$ $p = \pm\frac12(3 \pm \sqrt5).$
Therefore $p$ and $q$ are either 
$\frac12(3 + \sqrt5)$ and $-\frac12(3 - \sqrt5)$
or $-\frac12(3 + \sqrt5)$ and $\frac12(3 - \sqrt5)$ (in either order); 
so $p + q = \pm\sqrt5,$ $a = \pm2\sqrt5,$ and $b = -a.$
Therefore $a^2 + b^2 = 40.$