# How to find the maximal value of $a^2+b^2$ for $x^4+ax^3+3x^2+bx+1\geq0$

Tags: calculus, polynomials, optimization

Let $x^4+ax^3+3x^2+bx+1\geq0$ for all real value of $x$.
Find the maximal value of $a^2+b^2$. I think it will be 20, but how to prove that?

Comment: do you know a non-negative polynomial with $a^2 + b^2 = 20?$ You should type that in

Comment: I'll see your 20, and double it. I think you will find that $a = -\sqrt{20}, b = \sqrt{20}$ satisfies the constraint and produce $a^2 + b^2 = 40$. That disproves your thought.

Comment: Possibly duplicated: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169302/polynomial-maximization-if-x4ax33x2bx1-ge-0-find-the-maximum-value-o?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, so I leave it here. Not a complete answer.

There are three possibilities in this scenario. $f(x)$ has no real roots; $f(x)$ has two distinct real roots, each of which has multiplicity two; $f(x) = (x-r)^4$, for some $r\in\mathbb{R}.$ But it can be easily shown that the last scenario is impossible, since $r^4 = 1.$

In the first scenario, it must follow that $f'(x)$ has at most one real root, counting multiplicity. But $f'$ is cubic, so it must have at least one real root. Hence, $f'(x) = 4(x-c)(x^2+ex+d)$, where the quadratic has no real roots.

For the second case, $f(x) = (x-n)^2(x\pm \frac{1}{n})^2$.

Both of the cases seems doable - I could finish them up by tomorrow when I have time.